# extjs 4.2 grid store with ajax & paging

Tags: grid, paging, extjs4.2

I'm having the next problem, I have a grid with paging that is loaded via Ajax,
My problem is that i recieve about 8 millions of records, 
When I use paging I get from 1 to 25...etc

but when i load the pagingbar store it only gives me that i have only 25 records because my ajax only calls from 1 to 25... why is this? any ideas?

Regards

My code:

Store

> ```
> Ext.define('IE.store.reenvios.Reenvio', {
> ```
>
> extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
>     alias: 'store.Reenvios',
>     storeId: 'ReenviosStore',
>     model: 'IE.model.reenvios.Reenvio',

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        //
        read: 'resendTransaction/fetchResend'
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: '', 
        totalProperty: 'rowCount'
    }
},

autoLoad: false,
autoSync: false
```

});

Controller

> store.getProxy().extraParams = {
>             'folioType':folioT.value,
>             'folio':folioN.value,
>             'status':estatus.value,
>             'date':date.value,
>             'start':0,
>             'limit':26,
>             'pageSize':25,
>
> ```
>       'tamanoPagina':''};
>
>       store.load({...
> ```

Comment: What does your JSON response from the server look like?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the JSON response would be helpful, so I could see the name of the property that contains the total number of records.

I have a feeling the issue is because you set `totalProperty: 'rowCount'`. The property `rowCount` is likely the number of rows returned (ie, 25 or less), but you want the `totalProperty` set to the property that contains the total number of records. See the docs for more info. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-totalProperty